# Need Answer for (How to pass storage (User session) data to side menu ionic 5?)

Tags: ionic-framework

[How to pass storage (User session) data to side menu ionic 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039700/how-to-pass-storage-user-session-data-to-side-menu-ionic-5)

Answer (score 0):

you could just use

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key","value")
```

to store values session like. With

```
window.localStorage.getItem("key")
```

you can get back your stored value.